# I am getting an undefined variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve a file name from one page where the php script uploads the file (imageupload.php), and I  want to display it in another page within a javascript function (QandATable.php). But I don't know how to do this

I will show you all of the relevant code so you can follow it and so you are able to understand what is happening.

UPDATE: BELOW I WILL SHOW YOU THE STEPS ON HOW THE FILE IS UPLOADED. THE CODE BELOW SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADS THE FILE.

Below is the form (QandATable.php);

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
<label>Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
"<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
"</p><ul class='listImage' align='left'></ul>" +
"<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

On the same page when the user submits the form, it will go onto the function below, it will check for validation and then when validation is clear, it will go onto the `startImageUpload()` function:

```
 function imageClickHandler(imageuploadform){ 
      if(imageValidation(imageuploadform)){ 
          return startImageUpload(imageuploadform); 
      } 
      return false;
  }
```

If there is no validation then it will go onto the JS function (QandATable.php) below where it hides the file input and it will submit the form to the imageupload.php where the file uploading occurs. When the file is uploaded it then calls back to the stopImageUpload() function (QandAtable.php) where it will display the message on whether the file is uploaded or not and this is where I want the name of the file from the server to be appended.

Below is startImageUpload() function:

```
var sourceImageForm;

function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

$(imageuploadform).find('.fileImage').css('visibility','hidden');
sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;

return true;
        }
```

Below is the php script where it uploads the file (imageupload.php):

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    $result = 0;

    if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
        $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
        $ext = array_pop($parts);
        $base = implode(".",$parts);
        $n = 2;

        while( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
        $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
        "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
        $result = 1;

    }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
          "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
          $result = 1;     

          }

    ?>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.top.window.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);
</script>
```

Finally when upload is finished it goes back to the stopUploadImage() function (QandATable.php) to display the message on whether file is successfully uploaded or not. This is also where I want the uploaded file name from the server to be appended.

```
   function stopImageUpload(success){

          var result = '';
          if (success == 1){
result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
             $('.listImage').append('<br/>');
          }
          else {
result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
          }

    return true;

    }
```

Comment: First thing I see is missing quotes around this `var fileimagename = <?php echo $fileimagename; ?>;
` try `var fileimagename = '<?php echo $fileimagename; ?>';
`

Comment: Would have been good to see what the output JavaScript code looks like.

Comment: @Dale Still the same, still get the undefined variable

Comment: This is what it outputs on screen, Notice: Undefined index: fileimagename in /web/stud/xxx/Mobile_app/QandATable.php on line 19

Comment: i don't see where you set the `$_SESSION[' $_FILES['fileImage']['name']'];` variable

Comment: I can only guess that the issue is this `$_SESSION['fileimagename']` you are trying to use it when it doesn't have a value? or doesn't even exist I should say

Comment: Michael has put in his answer that it was the $_POST that was incorrect which caused the problem. But I am getting an error which states invalid regular expression flag w? what does this mean and how can it be fixed? Question above is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$_POST` won't contain `fileimagename`. Instead, your form input was called `fileImage`.  Use that instead:

```
// Check $_POST for fileImage, which was the form input name
if (isset($_POST['fileImage'])) {
  $_SESSION['fileimagename'] =  $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];
  // Proceed with the file upload and save.
}
else {
 // oops, can't proceed
}
```

On the JavaScript page, do some error checking when accessing the value:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['fileimagename'])) {
  $fileimagename = $_SESSION['fileimagename'];
  // output JS code...
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">Your JS code here...</script>
<?php
}
else {
  // No filename - can't proceed with JavaScript code
  // Display an eror or a message with instructions for user...
}
```

**Note:** Don't use the user-supplied filename to store the image! It opens you up to a directory traversal attack, and makes it possible for the user to write a file anywhere on your filesystem the web server has write-access to.

```
// This is unsafe!
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
```

Instead, it's common to store the value from `$_FILES['fileImage']['name']` in your database, along with an identifier value for the actual file, and use the identifier to store it on disk.

```
$info = pathinfo($_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
// Get the original extension
$filext = $info['extension'];
// Make a unique filename and add the extension
$stored_filename = uniqid() . $filext;

// Use that to store the file on disk
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], $stored_filename);

// Now store BOTH $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] and $stored_filename in your database together
// The original user-supplied filename can be used for display, but isn't used on disk
```

Comment: Hi, when you said don't use user-supplied filename, what do you mean, can you provide an example of a safer way to change that line of code?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on making uploading safer. I have updated my question and code, what has happended is that there is no undefined index error anymore but I am now getting an error stating invalid regular expression flag w? what does this mean? Question is updated to give you more info.

Comment: @user1341521 The invalid w flag is a red herring, due to the PHP error message that is being printed to the screen inside a javascript statement. In my code above, I abbreviated it, but what you really need to do is _not_ output the javascript at all if `$fileimagename` is not defined..  See above where I have `output JS code`. You need to wrap your JavaScript code inside the PHP if/else block.

Comment: In the php if statement code where I am suppose to output JS code, do you mean output the line of code: `var fileimagename = <?php echo $fileimagename; ?>;` or the whole javascript function (stopImageUpload()).

Comment: @user1341521 The entire function - whole contents of the `<script>` tag. If the variable isn't defined, that function cannot be run.  This may have other side-effects if you have a button or something which triggers that function - you wouldn't want to display that either then.

Comment: This should be last question and then I think the problem will be fixed and I can mark your answer. It is now giving me a invalid regular expression flag 2 in the other page (where uploading occurs) and it is on the bottom line if you look at code in question where it states: `<?php echo $fileimagename;?>`. how should I define $fileimagename? on that page?

Comment: @user1341521 Same idea - only output that script if the variable is set. `<?php if (isset($imagefilename)) { ?> <script>stuff...</script> <?php } ?>`

Comment: I have to go pick my brother up, I will be back in 1 hour. Look at the code I have now editted above in my question to show current code. The problem is that when I did what you have said in your last comment, then it doesn't upload anything as that the javascript function ` <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>,<?php echo $fileimagename;?>);</script>  
` doesn't take affect. Is my code correct. If not then please comment where I need to make the change :)

Comment: @user1341521 You have two parameters sent to your `stopImageUpload()` function when you have only defined it to take one.  If you changed it to pass `imagefilename` as a parameter, you must enclose it in quotes when echoing it from PHP since JS expects that it is a string.  `<?php echo "'$imagefilename'";?>`

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't work. It causes the upload to not work now. I hate this problem :(

Comment: @user1341521 At what point does the file upload fail? Does your form have the correct enctype? Does Is `fileImage` the correct form name attribute?

Comment: Before I tried retrieving the file name the uploading of the file worked correctly. It was when I tried to find the uploaded file name from the server and putting it in the javascript function that when the uploading fails. I have updated code to go back to when the files was uploading successfully. Please follow the code carefully and we will try and solve this together :) hopefully we can retrieve the uploaded file name from the server and append it in the "stopUploadImage()" function;

Comment: There were some pretty crucial details missing from your original post and from this conversation - specifically that this was an AJAX file upload performed from a dynamically created iframe.  That basically changes everything and invalidates most of the advice I've given you so far. I would suggest you ask a new question with all the details and all your code, and exactly the problem you're currently having